# Cakephp Dompdf Sizes

Tags: cakephp, dompdf

I've installed cakephp-dompdf-view plugin and followed all of the steps. It does work for sure, but the issue is that the generated PDF file get big sizes of each images and text. 
Please could anyone help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue? Do you mean that the images take up more of the page than expected? Some sample HTML/CSS and a screen shot of the output would help.

Answer (score 0):

I am using TCPDF in CakePhp 2.x and have no issues with big file sizes